# Do I need an EFI partition for each 18.04 ubuntu I have on my HD?

Tags: system-installation, uefi

I had to create an EFI partition to install ubuntu 18.04. Now I want to create another boot on the same HD with 18.04 again. Do I need to create another EFI partition?

Comment: So you will have two instances of Ubuntu 18.04 on one HDD?

Comment: yes,  @Pilot6 . The reason is irrelevant, but "My old 18.04 partition is going to fail soon due to bad block and Im moving to another one. As HP limits the number of partitions I can have, I care about creating new partitions".

Comment: HP doesn't limit the number of partitions. MBR maybe does.

Comment: @VitorAbella: If you're having accumulating bad blocks and impending data loss, you need to replace the entire disk, not just a single partition.  Reserved blocks are shared across the whole drive.

Comment: As always, I'd suggest [reading this](https://www.happyassassin.net/2014/01/25/uefi-boot-how-does-that-actually-work-then/) as a primer on UEFI. And then from a Ubuntu perspective you can either have multiple GRUBs managed by EFI, or one GRUB with muliple OSes managed by GRUB. But only ever the one ESP.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you only need one EFI partition. My dual-boot system shares the one partition between Windows and Ubuntu.

You can see it here with all the goofy Windows partitions. (My / partition is on a different physical drive)

[image]

Comment: so, when I install i choose my ubuntu efi partition that I already created?

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: I've only done it once. I created a new EFI partition, and the installer ignored it and used the existing Windows one.

Comment: @OrganicMarble That's not an EFI problem per se. Some computer's BIOSes always boot Windows if a Windows EFI binary is present, regardless of the user's boot choices. This is broken behavior, but since nearly all of the affected computers are several years old now, they're unlikely to be fixed.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I'm not speaking of booting but of installation.  There was already an EFI partition on the system, but following advice on this site, I created another EFI partition when installing Ubuntu as a dual boot.  The *installer* ignored the new EFI partition and used the pre-existing one created for Windows. Works fine though.

Comment: @OrganicMarble Oh, OK, I see what you mean. It doesn't really matter though, you can have as many EFI partitions as you want. If it bothers you, or you need the disk to be removable, you can move the relevant files from one EFI partition to the other (though you might have to tweak the boot order in the BIOS afterward).

Comment: @MichaelHampton: You can only have multiple EFI system partitions by violating the "globally unique" part of the GPT partition GUID.  In practice, locally unique (one EFI system partition per physical disk) should always be supported, to facilitate redundant and/or portable setups, but multiple on a single disk would violate the spirit of the rules for sure.

Comment: @BenVoigt Thanks for the clarification. I did indeed mean as many as you want, but one per physical disk.

Answer (score 4):

You need only one EFI partition for a computer in general.

No matter how many OS you have.

You may need multiple EFI partitions only in some special cases when you swap disks, change boot device in UEFI, etc.